# Word choice about a surgery/surgical operation having been done on somebody

Tags: word-choice

My friend Jack had a surgery/surgical operation last week. The operation was named operation 64 and the team who did the surgery was named Team P. To say this fact in a passive way, can we say the following?

> Jack was put under the surgery/operation 64 by Team P last week.

Any other suggestion is welcomed. What I am looking for here is a word/expression that can be used in a grammatically **passive voice** sentence to say such a fact. Also I want Jack to be the subject of that sentence. Moreover, I need the operation name, i.e. operation 64, and the doer, i.e. Team P, to be mentioned in the sentence.

Comment: So you want a word to fit into "Jack was ----- last week."? ***operated on***?

Comment: An operation was performed on Jack last week.

Comment: @Mrt I don't think this classifies as proofreading. The OP gave an example of the text and would like to know a better way to express it. It may be off-topic still, but not for proofreading. If he had asked, "Is there anything wrong with this sentence?", then that would possibly be proofreading.

Comment: The simplest way in English to say this is: Jack had surgery last week.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know the way to make a verb passive. I am just looking for the right word. And there actually are different forms that all are in a passive voice. Your suggestion **underwent** is not grammatically passive, even if there is a passive voice in it. I want a gramatically passive way to say what I want to say. But, then, I want Jack in the subject of the sentence. I am gonna edit the question.

Comment: @Mrt I agree with what the OP should do differently. But I still disagree that this is related to proofreading at all. As Fumble state, this may be better suited for ELL

Comment: @Hank http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/367764/reducing-adverb-clause-of-time You will find a comment that sounds very familiar.

Comment: @user204489: Not all verbs have "passive" forms. In your case perhaps the closest passive equivalent to ***had*** would be *He **was given** surgery.*

Comment: Guys, for me, this is a word choice question (if that matters!). The word(s) that is sought is one to say the above fact in a passive way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want passive voice, then:

> Procedure 64 was performed on Jack by Team P last week.

(note that the standard term in medicine for a specific type of surgery is 'procedure')

Comment: But, as mentioned, I want a sentence with Jack being the subject in it.

Comment: Upon Jack procedure 64 was performed by Team P last week?  That's pretty awkward.

Comment: The subject of the sentence with the verb "perform" is the procedure, not the patient.  "Jack was subjected to procedure...", but 'subjected' has a negative connotation.

Comment: Your last suggestion "subjected to procedure 64" is very close to what I want. Thanks. But how is its connotation negative?

Comment: "Subjected to" usually means that it was done without your willing participation or approval.  "I was subjected to a pat-down search at the airport" "I was subjected to a 2-hour wait at the bank"  "I was subjected to a lecture from my mother-in-law about how we are raising our children"

Comment: And what those doing procedure are called: Procedurer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51664/discussion-between-john-feltz-and-user204489).

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways of phrasing it in BrE:

- Jack had surgery last week.
- Jack had an operation last week.
- Jack underwent surgery last week.
- Jack underwent an operation last week.

It is a little more awkward to put it in the passive voice:

- Jack was operated on last week.
- Jack was given an operation last week.

> [**underwent**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/underwent) verb
>
> past simple of [**undergo**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/undergo) (to experience something that is unpleasant or something that involves a change)
>
> - After the accident, he underwent reconstructive surgery to rebuild his face.

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: None of your suggestions are passive. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @user204489 I missed that. The last suggestion is, in fact, passive. I'll try to add some more.

Comment: @user204489 What's wrong with "Jack was operated on by Team P last week."?

Comment: Please check the last edition.